# Stop NERDTree opening when vim starts

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have NERDTree plugin installed but it is always present when I start vim like this:

> vim .

I only want it to open on demand.

How can I stop it opening whenever I start vim?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding

```
let g:NERDTreeHijackNetrw=0
```

to your vimrc and make sure there is no other line that sets this variable.

Comment: I'm curious where do you get this info. I've taken a look at [this](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt) but I didn't find anything.

Comment: @Vdt From [docs](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/3e44d4ea5c3d8cfa192e66c77afd05629ddc92e6/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L616), just the same file. You’ve overlooked it.

Comment: @Vdt Don’t search for `g:Smth`, if you really read NERDTree help you should’ve noted all options go without `g:` prefix hence they are searched by `NERDTreeHijackNetrw`.

Comment: This does not work for gvim.

Answer (score 5):

`$ vim .` always opens a file explorer. If you don't have NERDTree or NERDTree is configured as per ZyX's answer you'll get `netrw` by default anyway.

I wonder what would happen if the `netrw` plugin was somehow removed.

Comment: You can easily test this with `gvim --noplugin .` and you get an empty buffer and the prompt "'.' is a directory".

Answer (score 4):

In your vimrc file, do below steps

1. comment `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree`, which stops opening nerdTree 
    by default
2. paste `map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` in vimrc, this will open 
   NerdTree only when 'Ctrl+n' is pressed from keyboard

Comment: I was using this approach for a long time. But for some weird reason, I am getting "E42: No Errors" when I press Ctrl + n. Do you have any idea why?